# Android App reports "not installed" due to permission error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest

On a tablet I installed a apk develloped in Eclipse under Ubuntu. The App works on the AVD and is already installed on a phone and working.
The installation of the apk gives no error, however when starting the App it gives a "not installed" toast message.

In the aLogCat output I see a Permission denial message of the Launcher for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Note that the USB connection is not connected when I started the App.

Furthermore I noticed the following line in aLogCat and I noted that the "-1" was added to the package name.

> ```
>    New package installed in /data/app/com.company.AppName-1.apk
> ```

In the manifest the lines

> ```
>    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
>    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
> ```

are in the manifest block and

> ```
>    <android:permission="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
> ```

in the application block.

Why is this working on a Android 2.3 phone and in a Android 4.0.3 AVD, but not on a Android 4.0.3 tablet?

Platform info: Eclipse 3.7.2, Tablet: Yarvik TAB461EUK; Installed with "ES File Explorer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the permission  from the application block. I dont know for sure but from personal experience ICS do not support permission attribute in application block which has already been defined in the main block. It inherits from the main block. Please tell if that solves the problem.

I dont know why it works on the AVD, may be because AVD do not have any external storage.

Comment: Perfect, It now works in the 2.3 and 4.0.3 AVD and on the 4.0.3 TAB. Cannot test it on the phone at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, but could you please give a link to documentation?

Comment: Glad to know it worked. @Lai Vung. The same error happened with me and that's how I know. I dont know any documentation to support it and thanks for pointing that. I have edited my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Related documentation:

`http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html` describes the permission element only for the main manifest block (now)

[Changes per version](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html) states:

> HONEYCOMB: When an application requires a permission to access one of its components (activity, receiver, service, provider), this permission is no longer enforced when the application wants to access its own component. This means it can require a permission on a component that it does not itself hold and still access that component.

[Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#prmsn) states:

> The name of a permission that clients must have to launch the activity or otherwise get it to respond to an intent. If a caller of startActivity() or startActivityForResult() has not been granted the specified permission, its intent will not be delivered to the activity.
>
> If this attribute is not set, the permission set by the  element's permission attribute applies to the activity. If neither attribute is set, the activity is not protected by a permission.

Not very clear to me